# Stetch image to fit to screen on background CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the image "desk.png" to be my background on a single web page with no scrolling. I want it to fit EXACTLY to the web browser. As of now I have:

```
body {
    background-image: url(desk.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

At this point the upper half the image is cut off. When I have tried other things, it has cut off a good portion of the bottom. I want to be able to resize it and keep a good resolution without cutting off anything.

Comment: Here is a solid way to achieve this with the use of jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/9e8vw/

Comment: body { background-size:cover;} would do it I believe!

Comment: @JoshPowell “Put the jQuery down and back away from the keyboard!” ;)

Comment: @coreyward LOL, I won't go down without a fight... All seriousness though, Thanks for your post! I love css and always had such a pain with full size images. +1 for that!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
body {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/5k9eH/7/**

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out, you can use the `background-size` property to do this in multiple ways.

#### Option 1: Resize without consideration for the aspect ratio (as @Danko pointed out):

```
background-size: 100%;
```

#### Option 2: Resize so the image is at least as large as the body (as @Zsigoveny pointed out):

```
background-size: cover;
```

#### Option 3: Resize so the image is as large as possible within the element:

```
background-size: contain;
```

These are all valid options, it just depends on what you want.

You can find more on `cover` and `contain` in the [background size documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size), and there is a great article on [Perfect Full Page Background Images](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) that you might enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
body{
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
body {
  background-image: url(desk.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat;
  background-position:center;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```